# Submitting a paper for review

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I have done some research and think I have interesting results. However, I have little experience in scientific publishing, especially in the mathematics domain (I am a Computer Science guy).

Can I post here a preliminary version of my paper, and get feedback regarding:

1. Whether the topic is interesting enough for publication? If so - where exactly? What journal/conference is the best fit?
2. Whether the presentation is enough high-quality? If not - how can I improve it?

Comment: This question is off topic here. And, I am reasonably sure this would be closed in the main site. (This means: I'd vote close but I cannot speak for the others.) It would be unfair to ask us read through your research manuscript. This is exactly the reason we have mentors at the institute where we study; the answer to (1) depends on what journal you are submitting your paper to: Clearly sending a different proof of a "well known" fact to Annals might be frowned upon; while it may be more welcome by MAA journals.

Comment: The answer to (2) would be: Submit the paper to a journal you think appropriate--The referres would tell you how to improve the exposition if it is interesting enough for publication.

Comment: But it is always very useful to ask someone like your mentor -- the professors in your department, before submitting something for publication.

Comment: Well, the problem is I am not in the math department, so I don't have mentors... How can a layman have is ideas reviewed?

Comment: I'm not sure why people are voting to close this question, which directly on topic for meta.

Comment: I agree with Zev. I voted to close so a re-opening process could begin early, I also voted to re-open (it would have been closed eventually anyway).

Comment: I cast a vote to reopen. If this question is to be closed, it is because it is likely to be a duplicate. I'm fairly sure that I have seen essentially the same question asked earlier. May be that was on Math.SE side (where it is off-topic)?  May be it was on MO?

Comment: The answer to the question is: No, do not post your paper here.

Comment: @Erel, but I'm afraid I agree with GEdgar. It is unlikely that anyone here would be willing to review your paper. This is a hobby (or an addiction), reviewing is work. I don't know whether an average editor would take a look, and comment on it, unless you actually submit it. They might (in the interest of saving their time, if your submission is unsuitable) and suggest a better journal, but they might not.

Comment: I was the first to cast the close vote. I did read the question but I don't recall why I decided this was off topic _here_. I apologise for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No, and no. Sorry, but this is very far from the purpose of this site.

Comment: While I agree with the other comments and Qiaochu's answer that you should not try to post the paper here and ask for review, your underlying question (that is: "How can someone who works in Computer Science with little contacts in Math Departments get some feedback about how and where to publish a mathematical paper?") is probably _on topic_ at http://academia.stackexchange.com/ And I am sure there you will receive some answers about how to get some feedback and how to find an appropriate journal to submit your manuscript.

Comment: Thank you, the link to academia.SE seems very useful.