# If I wrote an article related to math and ask for opinion in regard to my article, does it count as spam?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I wrote an article related to a mathematical subtraction equation. My question is, if I post a link to my article and ask for an opinion in regard to my article, does that count as spam?

Comment: Thank you for point that out.

Comment: @RajivKaipa correct (it has now been migrated) but the OP does not have the 5 reputation necessary to [post on Meta](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/participate-in-meta).

Comment: This older post seems related: [Submitting a paper for review](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4125). Perhaps also other questions [linked there](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/4125).

Answer (score 3):

Well, it might not be [spam](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/promotion), but consider the following:

- a question must be answerable *without* depending on the content found in external links. If the link breaks, the question may not become unclear. So post the relevant content in the question, and link to your article *if it provides some extra information*.
- questions asking for opinions are almost always [off-topic](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: Just to clarify, the "questions" you refer to are those that are posted in the main site, not necessarily those that are posted in meta.

Comment: Even questions on Meta can be off-topic for being primarily opinion-based, but far less likely so than on the main site.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, much appreciated.